# Access Calculated field in form or in table?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

What's better for database consistence? A calculated field in a Form or in a Table?

e.g I have a Table which has some Date Fields! I want to calculate them so I can to update status.

> [Start Date][End Date][Status]

I have a form to insert "Start Date" and "End Date"! So where is better to calculate it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the calculation which determines `[Status]`?

Comment: iif( [End Date] - [Start Date] <= 10 ; "On time" ; "Delayed" )

Comment: OK, you have a fairly simple expression to derive `[Status]`.  With Access 2010, you can make that a calculated field in the table.  However, why?  You can use the same expression in a query to derive `[Status]` whenever you need it.  In a form, you could use a similar expression as the Control Source property of a text box --- in that case, `[Status]` could update automatically whenever either of the date values change, even before those changes are saved to the table.  With respect to consistency, that would only be a problem if you store `[Status]` in the table.

Comment: True story! Gonna do That! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option for you besides what HansUp has mentioned is to create a stored query that includes that expression as a value, then make the form based off that query. That way you have the advantage of accessing status AS IF it's a column in the table (although it will be read-only).